# Function to return value based on date

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I'm trying to make a "Cash Flow" System, but instead of filling each cell manually, i want to pickup a value from other tab based on the dead line of an invoice i have.

For example: 
In TAB 01 i have a detailed version of my invoices, with date, name, itens, values, etc.
In TAB 02 i have my cash flow, wich is going to be auto-filled with the values of the invoices based on the dates.

I've been trying to do this with the INDEX and MATCH function, but my result is kind of weird.
This print screen is what i have so far: PS.: the Date format in my country is DD/MM/YYYY.

[image]

What i want is to show the C14 cell in the C3 cell. Or, for example, if my date on C15 is 06/05/2014, i want to show the C14 cell on the F3 cell.

Can anyone, please, help me?

Answer (score 1):

As I understand your question, you want to display the value of cell C14 in row 2, and below the cell that has the same date as cell C15.

The formula for that would be in cell A2

```
=IF($C$15=A1,$C$14,"")
```

Copy across.

I'm not sure that this is really what you want to achieve though. With this method you can watch only one date/value pair for a value.

You may want to step back a bit and explain the bigger picture. It looks as if the data architecture may need some improvement.

With regards to your use of the Index/Match:

- The index is on the first row, so a value from the first row will be returned, which is a date. Hence the big number returned by the formula (formatted as currency, not date)
- The Match function is all wrong. The second parameter must be a range, not a single cell. If you want to return an exact match, the last parameter must be a 0, not a 1

Comment: I'm not the advanced in Excel, so i might be doing soemthing wrong. But, let me try to explain my main idea for you. Let's say i have 3 bills to pay with the respective info= 1º: $400,00 02/05/2014 | 2º: $600,00 04/05/2014 | 3º: $800 06/05/2014. But i don't want to fill those infos direct to my cash flow in TAB 01. I want to put these info in the TAB 02 and make the excel Auto-fill my Cash flow based on those infos. Did you understand what i mean now? Anyway, thanks for your time =D

Comment: So, will you put these thee values into the same cells in Tab02, first $400, then overwrite $400 with $600, then overwrite with $800 and every time overwrite the date as well? In that case, the numbers will also disappear from Tab01 as soon as they are overwritten. Excel formulas are linked to the data that they refer to. If you overwrite the data for a formula with different data, then the formula will present a different result.  You need a totally different approach here. For example a table on Tab02 with Invoice Number, Name, Value, and Date as the column headers and each invoice ...

Comment: ... in its own row. Then you can use a pivot table in Tab01 to report on the data and display it in the format of your screenshot.